# KeyError: 'WEBP' in Pillow 7.2.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 with already installed libwebp-dev

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-imaging-library

I have managed to build Pillow 7.2.0 using pip like this:

```
pip install --upgrade Pillow==7.2.0 --global-option="build_ext" --global-option="--enable-webp"
```

Then in python console I've runned:

```
In [1]: from PIL import features
In [2]: print (features.check_module('webp'))
True
```

But my code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
with open(new_img, "bw+") as f:
    img.save(f, format="WEBP")
```

fails with:

```
~/src/myproject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self, fp, format, **params)
   2116             save_handler = SAVE_ALL[format.upper()]
   2117         else:
-> 2118             save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
   2119 
   KeyError: 'WEBP'
```

Is there anybody out there that has face this issue and can explain me how to fix it. Th
anks in advance.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the workaround is to import the Image from `WebPImagePlugin`, and not directly from the PIL.

`from PIL.WebPImagePlugin import Image`

Answer (score 1):

For docker users

I have added `RUN apk add --update --no-cache libwebp-dev` into my `Dockerfile` and it worked.
Note that my Pillow version is `Pillow==9.0.1`